# How to rename a class at Prestashop in override class?

Tags: prestashop

I know it is a stupid question. I am not familiar with the structure. The Prestashop is not like other PHP projects. I believe there must be a center file which contains all the required statements. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes in overrides must be named like that:

```
class Product extends ProductCore
{
    /* Your code. */
}
```

Please take attention to the prefix **Core**.